# How to use SharePoint 2013 REST service to retrieve data from lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, odata, json

I have two lists: 'Company' and 'Customer'. In 'Customer', I have an auto look up field called 'parent'. Then I tried to use Rest to retrieve data from customer like this:

`http://mysite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Customer')/items?$select=parent/Id&$expand=parent/Id`

But the response returned error: `<m:message xml:lang="en-US">The field or property 'parent' does not exist.</m:message>`

What can I do to get rid of this error.

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your query seems correct. Most probably this error occurs since `$select` and `$expand` operators are *case-sensitive*.

Try the following query:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Customer')/items?$select=Parent/Title&$expand=Parent
```

Comment: Hi, It's work perfectly !But with my autocompletelookupfield it's raise the same error.

Other information: the 'parent' column is the lookup field to 'Company' List and this is the autocompletelookupfield I customed, not Lookup field of SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the internal name of the fields in the query. Check the internal name of the 'parent' field, for example via PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite
$list = $web.Lists["Customer"]
$list.Fields | % { $_.InternalName }
```

or via

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Customer')/items
```

If the lookup field was renamed, it might have already a different title than you need.